# Find the One Random Set_id from each unique Skill_id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have my set table where there is set of question papers, There are 2 sets of question for each skills, I am looking to get any one random set of paper for each unique skill_id.

```
set_id      skill_id    set_name
----------- ----------- -------------
1           1           ENG1
2           1           ENG2
3           2           MTH1
4           2           MTH2
5           3           GRN1
6           3           GRN2
7           5           LOG1
8           5           LOG2
9           6           TEC1
```

The pattern for skills that I am looking for skill_id (1,2,3,5) and skill_id (1,2,5,6)

The output should be like

**for pattern (1,2,3,5)**

```
set_id      skill_id    set_name
----------- ----------- -------------
1           1           ENG1
3           2           MTH1
6           3           GRN2
7           5           LOG1
```

**for pattern (1,2,5,6)**

```
set_id      skill_id    set_name
----------- ----------- -------------
2           1           ENG2
3           2           MTH1
7           5           LOG1
9           6           TEC1
```

The code that I am trying to get the random numbers are

```
select (case when (select dbo.Random(1,2,RAND())) = 1 then max(skill_id)
  else min(skill_id) end)
  ,  set_id, set_name
from ques_set
where skill_id in (
  select val
  from Split((select skillsid from highest_qual where userid = 1 ), ',')
)
group by set_id, set_name
```

Comment: Question is in the different table that can be fetch once i can get the random set_id for each skill_id in the defined pattern

Answer (score 2):

you can use `order by newid()` to do the randomization

```
select *
from
(
    select set_id, skill_id, set_name,
           rn = row_number() over (partition by skill_id order by newid())
    from   ques_set 
    where  skill_id in (1,2,3,5)
) as d
where d.rn = 1
```